# Why does MS-SQL Databasestore INSERT INTO Data from Python-Code only temporary?

Tags: python, sql-server, database

At the beginning of these Example-Code i have 3 entries in the Database: "Old_1", "Old_2" and "Old_3". In the following Code i connect two times to the Database, each time i insert one entries and after this i call the "showall" function:

```
# Liberies
import pyodbc

# SQL-Account
dsn = 'sqlserverdatasource'
username = 'xxx'
password = 'xxx'
database = 'xxx'
con_string = 'DSN=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;' % (dsn, username, password, database)

def showall():
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    sqlstr = "SELECT sensless FROM test"
    cursor.execute(sqlstr)
    while True:
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if not row: break
        print row.sensless
    cursor.close()  

#TEST

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sqlstr = "INSERT INTO test (sensless) VALUES ('New_1');"
cursor.execute(sqlstr)
cursor.close()
showall()
cnxn.close()

print('------')

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sqlstr = "INSERT INTO test (sensless) VALUES ('New_2');"
cursor.execute(sqlstr)
cursor.close()
showall()
cnxn.close()
```

the following output were generated:

```
Old_1
Old_2
Old_3
New_1
------
Old_1
Old_2
Old_3
New_2
```

I am wondering, because of the missing "New_1" entrie by calling the "showall" function at the second time. It looks like the Database ist only saving the Data temporary. The question ist: Why? - Is this because i am connection with ODBC to the Database?

What do i have to change to get this result:

```
Old_1
Old_2
Old_3
New_1
------
Old_1
Old_2
Old_3
New_1
New_2
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to commit the transaction.

```
cnxn.commit()
```

See [the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted#Inserting_Data).